# Read key from App.config file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I want to read a key from `App.config` file in C# how can I do this?

I know I can use this,

`string filetype = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("filetype");`

but I don't want to use a hard-coded key.

The reason is that, in my project there are two libraries with separate app.config files, with separate keys.  I want to read the keys through one class only, without hard coding them.

Comment: "but i dont want to give hard coded value to AppSettings" - Why? Your only other option is using hard-coded code to read the config. Unless I'm wrong on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can always use a variable instead of `"filetype"` - is that enough not-hardcoded for you? What are you trying to achieve, really? *Edit: softcoded? how would you call that?*

Comment: Means in my project there are two libraries with separate app.config with separate keys. and i want to read that keys through one class only so that i don't want hard coded value.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  There's no way to use separate app.config files-- the best way I can think of would be to add your own XML file to the project and write the code to parse it.

Answer (score 6):

You can create strongly-typed sections in app.config, so that you won't need to use the "magic string" keys such as "filetype" in your example.

See: [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Creating the sections is somewhat involved, but there's an excellent Visual Studio plugin that generates all the code and schema from your design.  See:  [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

**Update**

Looks like I misunderstood the point of the question.  There's no way to use multiple *app.config* files, or an *app.config* file that is placed in a class library (as far as I know).  At runtime, all that's left of the class library is its DLL; by default any app.config file does not get copied over to the application by the *msbuild* process.

You may want to consider using your own XML configuration file within each class library, and setting its properties:

- `Build Action` to `Content`
- `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`

Comment: Does this apply to `App.config` as well?

Comment: @millimoose yes, app.config too.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by using configuration object as,

return Instance.GetConfigValue(strLst.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys.ElementAt(0));